# Reset sound volume in Windows 8

Tags: audio, windows-8, volume-mixer

There [seems to be a bug](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-sound/volume-level-randomly-lowers-to-a-very-low-level/23e03b8d-0aa7-4abe-91c5-aa356686ca61) in Windows 8 causing the maximum volume to become lower than it really should be. I'm now at a stage where I put the volume up to max and the sound is still very low. I have a couple of Logitech Z-10 speakers with a display on them and when I touch the increase volume button on that it shows me the volume (but not able to increase it) is actually below middle even though Windows claims it to be maxed out.

Is there any way I can reset the volume in Windows 8 so that I can get it up fully max again? A registry setting or something? Really don't want to have to reinstall windows or drivers or anything like that cause if it is a bug it'll probably happen again and I really don't want to have to do that every time this happens :p

Any ideas?

---

Manged to fix it by unplugging the usb connection to my speakers, turning the volume down on my computer and up on the speakers, and finally reconnecting the usb connection. Seems to have been an issue with the speakers and not Windows this time. BUT, I'm still curious how you can adjust/reset the Windows 8 sound volume without using the volume controls. Like, where is the value of the current volume setting(s) really stored? And can you manually adjust them?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with a programmatic solution, this might help with setting the volume:
[Vista Core Audio API Master Volume Control (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control)
[EndpointVolume API (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678715.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my Windows 8 MSI laptop. to fix it, I had to go to my soundcard options, and set no action as the action when the computer detects microphone communication.